# Where does Python look for library binaries?

Tags: python

I'm trying to bundle a Python library (fontforge) together so that my script runs on a machine without that library installed (but with Python installed). So far I tried copying ".so" files corresponding to "Missing library" errors to current directory, and while it worked for some, it didn't work for others, I'm getting "Missing library: libgunicode" even though I have libgunicode.so in current directory. Is there some setting I can adjust to get it to find it?

Edit: I'm on Ubuntu

**Update**: I got it to work  by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH=., then copying ".so" files into current directory until I got no more "library not found" messages

Comment: Details about your platform would be good.

Comment: Not sure if this is any use, but you can add a module to a script's path by using `sys.path.append("/home/me/mypy")`

Comment: I think it would be more elegant to just add all the required paths like so `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/lib1:/path/to/lib2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're on Linux, the OS looks for shared objects in the directories listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Here are all the details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#finding-shared-libraries